# Should I use 'hardware' to write NFC data to a empty tag?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I am a newbie developer but trying to develop an android app. I want to some functions of my app are run by NFC tag. But I'm a poor newbie, so I cannot solve questions below;

I tried NFC demo in android SDK with my nexus S, but that is just for NDEF data.
I think I should use foregrounddispatch() function..
NXP tag read/writer also don't have a function which enable write programming into tags. it is just for writing URL and text.

When searching empty tag providers I saw few providers are selling additional tag read/writer like normal RFID developer kit. Should I use that kind hardware to write my code to a empty tag?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Note that your question is rather unclear: 1. any interaction with reality needs to go through hardware at some point, can you clarify?; moreover, 2. this is not a site for shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use 'hardware' to write NFC data to a empty tag?

You do not have a choice. You need hardware that writes to NFC tags if you want to write to NFC tags. That hardware could be an NFC-capable Android device, or possibly some other sort of reader/software combination.

> There is NXP tag read/writer app in android market but the app is for NDEF data, not for code.

You do not put code on an NFC tag. You put data on an NFC tag.

Comment: Few tag providers also sell NFC tag reader/writer, not just android, NFC enabled cell phone. I have Nexus S, so what I'm curious is whether I should buy that kind of special reader/writer like RFID kit.

Comment: And android SDK provides also non-NDEF data writing and it is mentioned 'Advanced NFC' menu.. But I cannot find example and detailed explanation about that part.

Comment: @Eun: If you have a Nexus S, you should not need other hardware.

Comment: @CommonWare the other guy below this post said I should develop my own app to write another type of data.. what I want to make is to run a function of an app using foregrounddispatch(). For this case which tool I can use? always thanks to your answer:)

Comment: @Eun: "I should develop my own app to write another type of data" -- correct. "For this case which tool I can use?" -- you can write Android applications using any IDE you wish, though Eclipse is probably the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

To put custom data on a tag via Android, you need to write your own app.

Comment: It is sad news.. Now NXP app is totally useless for me.